# Javascript drop list with images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this on one of the subjects:
http://jsfiddle.net/GHzfD/357/
I would like to ask how to alert(path) after choose the image from drop list.

```
<script>
$("body select").msDropDown();

alert(???)
</script>
```

Comment: So you want to show an alert containing the path of the image that was last selected, each time an item is selected?

Comment: yes. may be just once as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body select").msDropDown();
  $("#webmenu").change(function(){
    alert($("#webmenu option:selected").attr('title'));
  });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/GHzfD/629/

Comment: If the answer is to your satisfaction, select it as the correct answer.

Comment: @user3347455, i'm glad to help...feel free to mark this answer as correct ;)

Comment: Yes I know... just had to wait 3 mins :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler to the msDropDown initialization parameters.

```
$("body select").msDropDown({
    on: {
        change: function(data, ui) {
            alert(data.image);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/GHzfD/630/

```
$("#webmenu").change(function(){
   alert($(this).find("option:selected").attr("title"));   
});
```